# javascript: round numeric values of N-dimensional array

Tags: javascript, arrays, multidimensional-array, rounding

I need to round values in array with the given precision. Array can contain any data types, so non-numeric values should be leaved 'as is'. Exaple for an array where two decimals needed:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function roundNumericValuesInArray(array, precision){
    var roundedArray = [];

    array.forEach(function round(elem){
        if(isNumber(elem)) {
            roundedArray.push(elem.toFixed(precision));
        } else{
            roundedArray.push(elem);
        }
    })

    return roundedArray;
}
var simpleArray = [5.454545, 8.456545646, true, 'fff'];
console.log(roundNumericValuesInArray(simpleArray, 2)); 
//["5.45", "8.46", true, "fff"]
```

Works good for 1-dimensional arrays, but when array contains an another array as it's element, this code won't work correctly, values in the inner array will not be rounded:

```
var twoDimensionalArray = [5.48878533, 4.8798765, [5.4843, 9.498787878, 'fff'], 5.4852, true];
console.log(roundNumericValuesInArray(twoDimensionalArray, 2));
// ["5.49", "4.88", [5.4843, 9.498787878, 'fff'], "5.49", true]
```

I've tryied to solve this with recursive call of round() function if elem is array, like this:

```
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function roundNumericValuesInArray(array, precision){
    var roundedArray = [];

    array.forEach(function round(elem){
        if(isNumber(elem)) {
            roundedArray.push(elem.toFixed(precision));
        } else if(elem.constructor === Array){
            round(elem);
        } else {
            roundedArray.push(elem);
        }
    })

    return roundedArray;
}
```

But interpreter throws "RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded", so it turns into infinite loop or something:

```
var twoDimensionalArray = [5.48878533, 4.8798765, [5.4843, 9.498787878, 'fff'], 5.4852, true];
console.log(roundNumericValuesInArray(twoDimensionalArray, 2));
//Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

So that's the problem: round values of numeric elements in multidimensional array, no matter how deep they are.

Output for

```
[5.48878533, 4.8798765, [5.4843, 9.498787878, 'fff'], 5.4852, true]
```

shoud be something like

```
[5.48, 4.87, [5.48, 9.49, 'fff'], 5.48, true]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case of an array pass it to `roundNumericValuesInArray()` and push the result into `roundedArray`

```
if(elem.constructor === Array){
    roundedArray.push(roundNumericValuesInArray(elem, precision));
}
```

```js
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function roundNumericValuesInArray(array, precision){
    var roundedArray = [];

    array.forEach(function round(elem){
        if(isNumber(elem)) {
            roundedArray.push(elem.toFixed(precision));
        } else if(elem.constructor === Array){
            roundedArray.push(roundNumericValuesInArray(elem, precision));
        } else {
            roundedArray.push(elem);
        }
    })

    return roundedArray;
}

var twoDimensionalArray = [5.48878533, 4.8798765, [5.4843, 9.498787878, 'fff', [1.2345, 2]], 5.4852, true];
console.log(roundNumericValuesInArray(twoDimensionalArray, 2));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterative and recursive approach with given arrays.

If an array is found, the result of the array is returned for mapping.

```js
function isNumber(n) {
    return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}

function roundNumericValuesInArray(array, precision) {
    return array.map(function iter(a) {
        if (Array.isArray(a)) {
            return a.map(iter);
        }
        if (isNumber(a)) {
            return a.toFixed(precision);
        }
        return a;
    });
}

var twoDimensionalArray = [5.48878533, 4.8798765, [5.4843, 9.498787878, 'fff'], 5.4852, true];

console.log(roundNumericValuesInArray(twoDimensionalArray, 2));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```